# Never Enqueued Stylehsheet

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

I never Enqueued the main stylesheet I'm using on my Wordpress site in the functions.php doc. I just uploaded the stylesheet to the site. Everything works, but I now want to dequeue the stylesheet on a specific page template. How would I go about enqueueing the stylesheet? I'm not sure why my stylesheet works even though I haven't enqueued it.

Any help would be much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Many themes hard-include `style.css`. Does your `header.php` file have something similar to  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style.css` is a requirement for any theme. Therefore you cannot dequeue it. You can however have a blank (except for the comments) style.css and enqueue another stylesheet for certain templates. To do so you would use `wp_enqueue_scripts()` like so :

```
function my_enqueue_style() {
  if ( is_front_page() ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mystyle.css' );
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_style' );
```

Comment: +1, but what about get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

Comment: good point- changed it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Common sense tells me I should Include this function near the top of my template code. Is that correct? Anywhere specifically it should go?

Comment: You're welcome :) Actually it should go in functions.php of you theme.